# Python Using sys.argv for vector/array input

Tags: python

Trying to write a Matlab script I have in Python.  First I have to do a dot product, and I want to test to make sure it's working.  Mechanical Engineer, not Software, so I'm getting blocked by lack of expertise.

```
import operator
def dot( vector1, vector2 ):
    dp = sum(map( operator.mul, vector1, vector2))
    return dp
```

So, first I set up my function.  Then, I have to call my function, right?  Like so:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    #dp = dot([2,5],[10,2])
    dp = dot(int(sys.argv[1]),int(sys.argv[2]))
    print dp
```

I am trying to run this by:

```
python dot.py [1,3] [3,1]
```

I can think of a bunch of reasons why `int([1,3])` won't work, but how do I code this correctly?

In the grand scheme of things, I'll be doing a bunch of "vector math" in my overall program; should I handle the values of each vector as separate entities?  This will be used by a bunch of people so I'd like to avoid downloading new libraries if possible.

Comment: var = eval("[1,3]"). NOTE: I wouldn't recommend to use this in production (obviously), but it's suitable for a program that will be used by you only

Comment: 0) Don't reinvent the wheel 1) Use NumPy 2) Make your users install NumPy easy on Linux, otherwise get them to install a distribution, e.g. Anaconda or Enthought

Answer (score 2):

I would do `%:> my_prog.py 1,3  3,1`

then process it

```
vect1 = map(int,sys.argv[1].split(","))
vect2 = map(int,sys.argv[2].split(","))
```

and for the love of programmign ... ***dont use eval*** .. if you really  want to at **least** use ast.literal_eval

```
import ast
v1 = ast.literal_eval("[1,3]")
```

it is **much** safer than eval

another (much better than eval)alternative is json (see other answer)

Comment: probably you meant sys.argv[2] in the second line

Comment: Noted on the eval and thanks; I work with enough software guys looking to tear me apart on such things :)

Comment: Really great answer, didn't know about `ast.literal_eval`. Looks like Python Object Notation analogue to JSON. :)

Answer (score 1):

If security is not an issue, I would do:

```
dp = dot(eval(sys.argv[1]), eval(eval.argv[2]))
```

`eval` just takes any string which looks like a python expression and returns value of that expression.

**UPD:** better solution

```
import json

...

dp = dot(json.loads(sys.argv[1]), json.loads(eval.argv[2]))
```

P.S. It will work only if you place space only between two arrays, else `sys.argv` will contain more elements.

Comment: arrggg... since you prefaced it with `if security is not an issue` i wont downvote... but in my experience eval is very rarely the "right" answer and is very scary (especially if your program will go out into the "real world")

Comment: @JoranBeasley Oh, now I think about better idea. JSON.

Comment: much better :) (and faster i think :P, not that speed is an issue)

Comment: Interesting!  I'll give this a try for fun as well --  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using eval of the arguments will solve your problem. This will treat the arguments as actual python statements instead of strings that need to be parsed into a data type.

```
dp = dot(eval(sys.argv[1]),eval(sys.argv[2]))
```

This isn't a great solution in general though as you're probably going to come across more problems in the future. You might be better of reading from a file using JSON data or something.

Comment: eval is a huge security hole ... I would almost never recommend this method ... especially to a new programmer who then may use eval in even less secure environments ...